# How to set csplit output filenames by pattern?

Tags: text-processing, files, split

Is there a way to set output names of `csplit` through the pattern?
I want to split the ssh-config by hosts to corresponding files.

If there is a solution without `csplit` I'm happy as well.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input and expected output.

Comment: You can't do that just with `csplit`, you'll have to either rename the pieces after splitting or use a more advanced tool like `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `csplit` can only use integer numbering in output file names. If you want to base the output file on the content, use another tool, for example awk or perl.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {out="_"}
    $1 == "Host" {if ($2 ~ /\//) exit(1); out=$2}
    {print >out}'
```

Note that this code only performs rudimentary error checking (I did at least make sure that it would only write in the current directory). Don't run it on an untrusted file.